# adding values that could contain a null/undefined value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sorry to ask, but I just can't find the info.

My script needs to add 12 items together but some of them may have null/undefined values

ie

1 + null + 3 + 4 + null + null + 7

How do I add these together?

```
$scope.wepweight = ($scope.selectedWeapon1Ship1.Vars.weight) +($scope.selectedWeapon2Ship1.Vars.weight)
```

At the moment, the values will add together once all the ng-models are populated (because of the null/undefined values), but I need to keep a running total.

https://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/3u6ob98d/2/

(search for "//calculate weight for hull" within the JS section to see the relevant section of code)

Answer (score 3):

You could take the [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) which checks if the value is `null` or `undefined`, then it takes the right hand side value.

```js
const sum = 1 + (null ?? 0) + 2 + (undefined ?? 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `||` operator to check if the value is `null` or `undefined`, and if it is, add `0` to it:

```js
console.log(1 + (null || 0) + 3 + 4 + (undefined || 0) + 7) // 15
```

Comment: I tried the || 0 approach and it still never added the values

Comment: @WayneGilliver `(variable === null ? 0: variable)` - Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify where you got your values from, but either they are stored in an array or you can put them in an array.
Once you have them in an array, it's elegant with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
// assuming weight is your array
weight.reduce((a,b) => typeof b === 'number' ? a + b : a, 0);
```

What this code does is that it starts with 0 and adds every element that is a number (which `null` is not)

Answer (score 0):

i think this one can help you

```
$scope.wepweight = calcSumValue();
function calcSumValue() {
   let ans = 0;
   for(let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
       const value = $scope[`selectedWeapon${i}Ship1`].Vars.weight
       if (value)
           ans += value;
   }
   return ans;
}
```

Comment: i have added my fiddle to the OP so you can see (search for //calculate weight for hull within the JS section)